# MySQL, conditional WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

Here's my statement:

```
SELECT
    a.size AS 'size_id',
    b.size,
    a.stock,
    a.id AS 'stock_id',
    IFNULL(c.quantity,0) as 'cart_qty'
FROM
    stock a
JOIN 
    sizes b ON a.size = b.id
LEFT JOIN
    cart_items c ON a.id = c.stock_id
WHERE
    a.product_id = '{$product['id']}'
AND
    c.cart_id = '$cart_id'
AND
    a.stock > 0
ORDER BY
    b.display_order
```

In the above, $cart_id might be blank, or it might have no matches in the 'cart_items' table. How do I rephrase the above so that if there are no matches in cart_items, I still get the results from stock that match product_id? But if there are matches in cart_items then I get the additional column (cart_qty)?

Comment: If you want to get the product info whatever it's in the cart, why are you limiting the result by cart_id? Just remove the `AND c.cart_id = $cart_id`

Comment: @Keiran Tai this runs when the standard product page is loaded. So IF the product is already in the user's shopping cart, I want to know the quantities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the predicate to `ON` clause:

```
LEFT JOIN
    cart_items c ON a.id = c.stock_id AND c.cart_id = '$cart_id'
```

This way,  if there are no matches in `cart_items`, you still get the results from `stock` that match `product_id`. Otherwise, if there are matches in `cart_items` then the additional column `cart_qty` is properly filled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do both. But first one in case `$cart_Id is null` you add

```
AND ($cart_Id is null or c.cart_id = '$cart_id')
```